# Get specific value from text

Tags: php, parsing

Hi I have a cookie with this value in it

```
a:2:{i:0;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:5196;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"209";s:5:"price";d:1;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:12:"product_name";s:4:"test";s:11:"thumb_image";s:0:"";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}i:1;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:4617;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"211";s:5:"price";d:1200;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:74:"Машка блуза,EXTERRA ГТЦ 1 спрат и CITY MALL 1спрат";s:12:"product_name";s:0:"";s:11:"thumb_image";s:42:"thumb_e069100cef8553637664fc695df55c66.JPG";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}}
```

And i need to read the value and get any number that is in the position of the number 5196 in the text, right after "product_id"; i: . So anybody has an idea how can i get the number 5196 using php?

Comment: Is the format always the same? If so, some PHP string functions should work just fine. Find the location of that character sequence. Take everything from the end of it to the next semicolon. BOOM HEADSHOT

Comment: @thatidiotguy yap its always the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be very opposed to working directly with serialized data if possible. Rather, I would unserialize the data using [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), and then grab the value from the resulting array.

```
$data = 'a:2:{i:0;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:5196...';
$rslt = unserialize($data);

echo $rslt[0]["product_id"];
```

Run this code: http://codepad.org/JKYUS6yd

Answer (score 1):

That string is a serialized object. If you unserialize it, you can loop through it and find the array that has product_id = 5196, and do what you want with it, e.g. get its other values:

```
$str = 'a:2:{i:0;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:5196;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"209";s:5:"price";d:1;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:12:"product_name";s:4:"test";s:11:"thumb_image";s:0:"";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}i:1;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:4617;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"211";s:5:"price";d:1200;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:74:"Машка блуза,EXTERRA ГТЦ 1 спрат и CITY MALL 1спрат";s:12:"product_name";s:0:"";s:11:"thumb_image";s:42:"thumb_e069100cef8553637664fc695df55c66.JPG";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}}';
$unserialObj = unserialize($str);
foreach($unserialObj as $item) {
    if($item['product_id'] == 5196) {
        echo $item['cateogry_id'] . ', ';
        echo $item['price'];
        //etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'a:2:{i:0;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:5196;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"209";s:5:"price";d:1;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:12:"product_name";s:4:"test";s:11:"thumb_image";s:0:"";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}i:1;a:17:{s:8:"quantity";i:1;s:10:"product_id";i:4617;s:11:"category_id";s:3:"211";s:5:"price";d:1200;s:3:"tax";s:5:"18.00";s:6:"tax_id";s:1:"1";s:11:"description";s:74:"Машка блуза,EXTERRA ГТЦ 1 спрат и CITY MALL 1спрат";s:12:"product_name";s:0:"";s:11:"thumb_image";s:42:"thumb_e069100cef8553637664fc695df55c66.JPG";s:3:"ean";s:0:"";s:10:"attributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:16:"attributes_value";a:0:{}s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:9:"vendor_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"files";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:14:"freeattributes";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:25:"dependent_attr_serrialize";s:6:"a:0:{}";}}';
$ar = explode(";",$str);
$ar2 = explode(":",$ar[4]);
print_r($ar2[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

using a regex:

```
$cookie = 'value from your post';
preg_match('/.*"product_id";i:([^;]+)/', $cookie, $matches);
$product_id = $matches[1];
```